# Can I avoid the object variable name in ng-repeat loop?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

When defining an ng-repeat directive to iterate over an array, the syntax specifies `ng-repeat="friend in friends"`, and then within the template you use the interoplation operator like so `{{friend.name}}`.

Is it possible to have the properties assigned to the current item scope, rather than a variable in it? So I could call just `{{name}}` instead of `{{friend.name}}`?

The reason being is that my directive is being used in the scope of two different templates - for example I might have a directive `"userActions"` that is used in both a repeater, and also inside an unrelated template where `{{friend.name}}`  doesn't make sense. I would like to avoid artificially manufacturing the `friend` object where it doesn't have a semantic meaning.

---

**My use case is something like this:**

I have a grid that renders blocks of various types. Some psuedo code:

```
<div ng-repeat="block in blocks">
   < cat block />

   < friend block >
         <userActions directive />
   </ friend block >

   < guitar block />

   .... more blocks
</div>
```

I also have a friend page, that contains the exact same user actions:

```
..fragment of friend page..
  <element ng-control="friend">
     <userActions directive />
  </element>
```

Now, if I want to user a property of the block inside the repeater, the syntax is `{{block.name}}`. So the template for `userActions` contains this.

However, once I use this template in the *friend* page, I must create `{{block.name}}` inside the scope of the friend controller. This does not make sense though, because the block only exists in the context of the block grid. I shouldn't have to create this `block`.

What I want to be able to do, is just to call `{{name}}` from within the `userActions` directive template, since both the block scope and the controller contain it. I don't want to create a `block` object, then artificially set `block.name` in each scope where I want  to use the `userActions` directive.

**Here's a [jsFiddle to illustrate the cause](http://jsfiddle.net/opherv/b7KEm/)**

Comment: I am assuming here that the example you have provided is just for illustration purposes and what you are attempting is more complex? Could you perhaps describe what you are trying to do? There should be something common in between friend and block - yes? Or else it doesnt make sense that you are using the same template for both of them.

Comment: Btw here is a fiddle that solves your problem. Not sure if that is what you are looking for. You need to note that we are now creating an isolate scope. http://jsfiddle.net/b7KEm/6/

Comment: Yeah the fiddle just represents a reduced example of the problem. Obviously my app is much more complex :) Let me elaborate - Block represents a view of several possible entities. One of these entities is "friend". Each friend entity has a set of user actions that can be associated with it. For our example - actions are "kill" and "hug". These actions can be performed from *both* the context of the friend block as well as the friend page. They contain the same template and logic and thus share the same directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've decided to combine the informative answers of [Mathew Berg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/973651/mathew-berg) and [ganaraj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15810755/can-i-avoid-the-object-variable-name-in-ng-repeat-loop#comment22494624_15810755) with my newfound knowledge to create a helpful answer to this.

The short answer is **You really don't want to do that**.

---

The longer answer is this:

When using `ng-repeat="block in blocks`" , a new scope is created for each block element, and the properties of every block object are create in `scope.block` of each block. This is a good thing, because this means all properties can be accessed by reference, updated or $watched.

If `ng-repeat` wouldn't have done that, and all properties would just be slapped unto the block's scope, then all primitives in `block` (strings, ints, etc) would just be copied from the block object to the block scope object. A change in one will not reflect on the other, and that's bad. [More info on that here.](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/The-Nuances-of-Scope-Prototypal-Inheritance#wiki-ngRepeat)

Ok so now that we've decided that's a good thing rather than a bad thing, how do we overcome the semantic issue? I've decided to use the `friendData` object container as the object on the scope of my directive, and so the directive expects the `friend-data` attribute to hold the relevant properties

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
.directive("lookActions", function(){
    return {              
        restrict: 'E',        
        template: "<input value='Kill -{{ friendData.name }}-' type='button'>",
        scope : {
            friendData : '='            
        }
    }
});
```

This way I can assign this object regardless of which context I'm calling my directive template.

Given these controller contexts:

```
function gridCtrl($scope) {    
    $scope.blocks = [{ type: "cat", name: "mitzi"},{ type: "friend", name: "dave"},{ type: "guitar", name: "parker"}];
}


function friendCtrl($scope) {    
    $scope.data={
        name: "dave"
    }
}
```

How to call the directive -

Within an `ng-repeat`:

```
    <div class="block" ng-repeat="block in blocks" >            
        <look-actions friend-data="block" />
    </div>
```

Or in a difference context:

```
    <div ng-controller="friendCtrl">  
         <look-actions friend-data="data" />
     </div>
```

Here's the [solution Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/opherv/pJ6Y9/)

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how you structure your directive. It's hard to tell without a fiddle/plunkr what your code looks like so I'm taking a stab in the dark here. Right now I think what you're trying to say is that in the context of where you're using your directive friend.name does not make sense. Perhaps something more generic like person.name might be more appropriate. In that case you can do the following so that you pass in to the directive what you want the person to be associated with:

**Html**

```
<div data-ng-repeat="friend in friends">
    {{ friend.name }}
    <div class="myDirective" data-person="friend"></div>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
.directive("myDirective", function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        scope: {
            person: "=person"
        },
        template: "<div>{{ person.name }}</div>"

    }
});
```

**jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/5aVLf/1/

Comment: Appreciate the input, but this isn't my use case. I've edited my question, hopefully it's somewhat clearer now. I want to avoid creating the `person` object in the directive scope.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: I've created a jsfiddle, please take a look

Comment: Thank you for your effort. While this might technically work, it doesn't feel like an elegant solution. If I have 20 properties in my block object, it means that I need to set those 20 properties in the block-object attribute - long and cumbersome. Moreover, if I'm using the template this way on several pages, then I will have to recreate this list of properties for each and every page, which isn't very DRY-oriented, and probably hard to maintain.

Comment: Also, in your answer you wrote "Perhaps something more generic like person.name might be more appropriate". The problem is not the *naming*, but the fact that the *scope* is incorrect. When lookActions directive is used in the friend page, all properties are flat in the scope. There is no "block" or "person" for that matterm because the scope itself represents that. When used in the repeater, every block has its own scope, but the scope contains the extra variable for "block" with the desired properties, instead of exposing the properties in the scope.

Comment: You can achieve what you're talking about with all the properties flat on the scope but I would highly advise against it. You have no guarantee of where you use it that you might not end up with a collision somehow since you're using a directive. For instance, you might have a click function wired up in that directive and then unknowingly come along later and name a property in the object you're passing in that would get overwritten by the function. While I did use {name: name} that was just because you had the variable set up like that in controller.

Comment: Actually, after reading [this article](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/The-Nuances-of-Scope-Prototypal-Inheritance#wiki-ngRepeat) I realize the having properties flat out on the scope is bad for an entirely different reason - if the scope has primitives they will not work with data binding.  I guess there's no way around passing all properties inside an object. You did help me by opening my eyes to setting up that object using an attribute and inheriting it in isolate scope. I will attempt your suggestion! Thanks! :)