# Implicit variable name in an Angular ng repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Consider I have a few objects, each of them having the properties `x`, `y` and `z`.

Now consider I have the following Angular ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in objs">
    Values are: {{ obj.x }}, {{ obj.y }} and {{ obj.z }}
</div>
```

Is there any way I can implicitly use the `obj` variable, so I could do:

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in objs">
    Values are: {{ x }}, {{ y }} and {{ z }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do doesn't seem to be a good idea, as per [this answer to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15820251/2982954). Basically, because... (switch "block" for "obj")

> (...) all primitives in block (strings, ints, etc) would just be copied from
>   the block object to the block scope object (...)

That's the basic reason for directives like ng-repeat making a new scope of their own.

I see your point in trying to save some keystrokes, but it's not like you can't just copy & paste ;)

Comment: I haven't said anything about using that as a directive template. Actually, I'm going to compile this against an array of objects, so the only variable the template would see is that object, nothing more.

Comment: Regardless of being a directive template or not, it still is not a good idea: the risk of running into conflicts and other issues is too high just to save "a couple" of keystrokes. If you still want to take the risk, I would probably give ng-init a try...

Comment: I really can't see those risks. Care to explain a little bit further?

Comment: From https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#ng-repeat: _"If item is a primitive (as in myArrayOfPrimitives), essentially a copy of the value is assigned to the new child scope property. Changing the child scope property's value (i.e., using ng-model, hence child scope property num) does not change the array the parent scope references."_

Comment: There is no such thing in an interpolation. Are you sure you understand how `$interpolate` actually works?

Comment: I'm realizing I probably don't understand your original question in the first place...

Comment: So, an interpolation is, basically, taking a string template and compiling it against an object, replacing the values of the object with the delimited placeholders in the template. There are no scopes whatsoever involved in that. That is why I insisted in asking "what conflicts?"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80798/discussion-between-davguij-and-alexandernst).

Comment: @alexandernst, this is absolutely correct. Original `ng-repeat` had just such an option, but broke in various use cases. For example, in nested repeats, you would struggle to specify your focus object.

Comment: @DaveAlperovich Oh well, I guess I'll have to find my way into manually interpolating what I need. Thank you anyways

Comment: @alexandernst, not knowing your full needs, I'd suggest using directives and templates may be your answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you were to have it in this format:

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in objs">
    Values are: {{ x }}, {{ y }} and {{ z }}
</div>
```

Then that would mean that x, y, z are variables on the scope. So that conflict prevents you from having an implicit variable like that, except if you actually put that variable on the scope through a helper function, but! that would create overlap between scope variables having the same name per each object in the array, so either way you have a naming conflict.

Sorry, I usually don't do proofs, but hopefully this can prove by contradiction why that would be impossible. Hope that helps!

Comment: I haven't said anything about using that as a directive template. Actually, I'm going to compile this against an array of objects, so the only variable the template would see is that object, nothing more.